# Posting data to server async just before page redirect

Tags: javascript, html, web

It seems like a common problem, but I couldn't find related threads - please direct me if I missed something here.

we are using some sort of click tracker to our website. 
this tracker is getting calls when the user click on a link, we want to populate certain data to a different  server, and let the user continue to the clicked url.

As I do not want to wait for the server response here- I am not waiting for response to this ajax call.
but what happens is the I lose this call and it never gets to the server.
What is the correct way to perfrom this action?

I am using  top.window.location.href = url; as I sometimes get opened in an Iframe.

```
function onClick(url, clickedFrom) {
        var testClick = ServerHost + "click";
        var dataObject = buildCommonData();

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'post',
            contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataObject,
            url: testClick,
            async: true,
            success: function (response) {
                top.window.location.href = url;

            },

        });
        top.window.location.href = url;

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You need to wait for a response before unloading the page.

Comment: The `$.ajax()` call is not getting enough time to call the server, because of the second `top.window.location.href` call @Kiran. But yes @briler, you do need to wait if you *must* be sure the tracker is triggered.

Comment: @digitalextremist the ajax call is already placed, however the callback will not be executed as he is redirecting.

Comment: @Kiran... the OP said: *what happens is the I lose this call and it never gets to the server* ... it's not about the response or callback... The second redirect ( outside the `success:` block ) is clobbering the call.

Comment: Right, thats why I said, it's a decision on what OP wants, than, what to do. If he needs to wait, all he has to do is to remove the redirect and move it into success/error callbacks.. but he doesn't want to wait in which case, what he has works.

Comment: you should have `top.window.location.href = testClick;` on success, failure and error blocks. i think `testClick` is better. remove the last redirect before return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second `top.window.location.href = url;` ... that is clobbering your `$.ajax()` call... and `return false` is never reached.

---

Consider using `setTimeout` **and** `success:` on the `$.ajax()` call!

You can double-up your approach here, and keep the second `top.window.location.href` call, but put it in a `setTimeout` block, in case there is an `$.ajax()` delay.

This way, the `$.ajax()` call *should* happen first, but if not, at least the user is not delayed if/when there is a server glitch that hangs up the `$.ajax()` call.

Comment: I thought about timeouts- but I do not want to let the user wait here.

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks, I end up with the top.window.location.href = url on ajax  success & failure, also added timeout property. as I do not want to user to wait to long. removed the out of ajax scope top.window.location.href = url as it did not get to send the ajax call. Tahnks for your help.