# Ajax function won't fire on a class when href when target is a downloadable file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm recording download counts to my database using AJAX to fire a php function but I'm having an issue where my function isn't firing on any classes with an href that contains a downloadable mp3 file.

Example link :

```
<a class="pod-download" href="https://example.com/file-772325/download" data-id="772325">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

This is the AJAX :

```
jQuery(document).on('click', "a.pod-download", function(event) {

    var trackID = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');

    var data = {
            'action': 'addDownloadCount',
                'security': jQuery( '#crate-nonce' ).val(),
                'trackID' : trackID
               };

    var $this = jQuery(this);

    jQuery.post(myCrate.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        $this.closest('.podwrap').find('.ps-downloads').html(response);

    });

});
```

The AJAX function DOES work however if I use preventDefault :

```
jQuery(document).on('click', "a.pod-download", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var trackID = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');

    var data = {
            'action': 'addDownloadCount',
                'security': jQuery( '#crate-nonce' ).val(),
                'trackID' : trackID
               };

    var $this = jQuery(this);

    jQuery.post(myCrate.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        $this.closest('.podwrap').find('.ps-downloads').html(response);

    });

});
```

But then the file obviously doesn't download.

So my question is how can I make the AJAX function fire as well as actually allowing the file to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY:

```
<a class="pod-download" href="https://example.com/file-772325/download" data-id="772325" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

OR:

adding the followings after event.preventDefault();

```
window.open( mp3_download_url, 'mp3');
```

To avoid you page from refreshing and allow the AJAX POST being executed

Comment: Both of those work, the latter being the most preferable. Thanks @nlgn

Comment: @Grant If you use window.location.href = url;, it may be better put it inside the ajax callback. I am worrying your updated code doesn't work in IE. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment the answer below. Ref: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096926/posting-data-to-server-async-just-before-page-redirect[/link]

Comment: Ahh ok, I don't use IE (or PC's) for that matter, so would be good to know why the answer I posted below wouldn't work in IE as I can't test it.

Comment: And do mean just by moving it into the response part of my function that it WOULD work in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Actually expanding on @nlgn's answer I came up with the following which is much nicer in case anybody else is attempting this.

I changed the a href into a span and added the download url as a data ref :

```
<span class="pod-download" data-url="https://example.com/file-772325/download" data-id="772325">DOWNLOAD</span>
```

Then in the script instead of using window.open, we use window.location.href which prevents the annoying blank window popping up :

```
jQuery(document).on('click', ".pod-download", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var trackID = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('data-url');

    window.location.href = url;

    var data = {
                'action': 'addDownloadCount',
                'security': jQuery( '#crate-nonce' ).val(),
                'trackID' : trackID
               };

    var $this = jQuery(this);

    jQuery.post(myCrate.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

        $this.closest('.podwrap').find('.ps-downloads').html(response);

    });

});
```

Works like a charm and is really clean.